# Form data not being sent in the email

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Below is code that I have that I basically just mimicked. A professional web developer made the website, so im just following how they did it. But, for some reason the data does not get sent in the email. But, the email does send.

## controller file

```
def createproject
@title = "Create Your Project"
@txtname = params[:txtname]
@txtemail = params[:txtemail]
@txtdates = params[:txtdates]
@tname = params[:tname]
@txtleader = params[:txtleader]
@txttree = params[:txttree]
@txtsolar = params[:txtsolar]
@txtwater = params[:txtwater]
@txtgoats = params[:txtgoats]
@txtkids = params[:txtkids]
@txthouse = params[:txthouse]
@txtroof = params[:txtroof]
@txtlatrine = params[:txtlatrine]
@txtbuild = params[:txtbuild]
if !@txtname.nil? && @txtname != '' 
  @isvalid = true
  @data = {
    :txtname => @txtname,
    :txtemail => @txtemail,
    :txtdates => @txtdates,
    :tname => @tname,
    :txtleader => @txtleader,
    :txttree => @txttree,
    :txtsolar => @txtsolar,
    :txtwater => @txtwater,
    :txtgoats => @txtgoats,
    :txtkids => @txtkids,
    :txthouse => @txthouse,
    :txtroof => @txtroof,
    :txtlatrine => @txtlatrine,
    :txtbuild => @txtbuild
  }
end
if @isvalid
  ContactUsMailer.createproject_mail(@data).deliver
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {render :layout=>"homeLayout"}
  end
else
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {render :layout=>"homeLayout"}
  end
end
end
```

## mailer file

```
def createproject_mail(data)

@data = data

@txtname = @data[:txtname]
@txtemail = @data[:txtemail]
@txtdates = @data[:txtdates]
@tname = @data[:tname]
@txtleader = @data[:txtleader]
@txttree = @data[:txttree]
@txtsolar = @data[:txtsolar]
@txtwater = @data[:txtwater]
@txtgoats = @data[:txtgoats]
@txtkids = @data[:txtkids]
@txthouse = @data[:txthouse]
@txtroof = @data[:txtroof]
@txtlatrine = @data[:txtlatrine]
@txtbuild = @data[:txtbuild]

mail(:to => "jacob@fusionbible.com", :subject => "TEST", :from => "no-reply@mohhaiti.org")
end
```

Comment: Is value of @isvalid true ?

Comment: @neo isvalid is true as this code ia sending email but without data.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure what i'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: @jworth can you please share your email template.

Comment: finally figured out what i was doing wrong. It had nothing to do with those files. There was an html file that had all the values that were suppose to be sent in the email. the file was called createproject_mail.html.erb.html. I had to fix the naming issue.

Comment: @PardeepDhingra is there a way instead of a check box saying "on" to have it say something else in the email?

Comment: @JWORTH yes we can do that. But i need to see your html email template, how you are showing checkbox in it.

Comment: @PardeepDhingra     https://github.com/jacobgworth/samplerepo2

Comment: @PardeepDhingra have a new question for you!  github.com/jacobgworth/samplerepo2  I added all files. Right now each of the checkbox's have a price to them. It displays properly on the page itself. But, how would I get the options selected plus the price of them to display on the email?

Comment: @JWORTH i have added few changes in you repo..for two check boxes tree and solar..you can copy those changes for other checkbox too..

Comment: @PardeepDhingra for some reason i dont see any of those changes made in the repo

Comment: @JWORTH its forked to my account https://github.com/railites/samplerepo2

Comment: @PardeepDhingra the last commit was made 12 hours ago. Do you mind just emailing me the code? jacob@fusionbible.com

Comment: @PardeepDhingra OH. Nevermind. I did not realize you made mult branches haha

Comment: @PardeepDhingra the only thing is I dont want to have the value show by the Yes or no. I want it basically to function like it does on the actual page.

Comment: Where it adds the prices that were selected and displays a total

Comment: I already mailed you code and in formcalculation.js, Check line 16 and 33. Where its adding price into hidden fields which are going to be passed into controller after submit.

Comment: @PardeepDhingra  guess you dont see what im saying haha. Basically in the createproject_mail.html.erb at the end there is TOTAL PRICE:   How would I add the prices? Like what is the proper syntax. I get that the prices are being passed into the controller, but I dont know how to add those prices together in the html file. Does that make more sense?

Comment: @JWORTH please come on chat to discuss this as that code is already there.

Comment: @PardeepDhingra if you could please come on chat that would be awesome!

Comment: @PardeepDhingra im available to talk if you are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in application_helper.rb

```
def humanize_checkbox(val)
  (val && 'on' == val.downcase) ? 'Yes' : 'No'
end
```

Add this in your mailer class.
  `helper :application`

and for checkbox in view call it

```
<%=humanize_checkbox(@txttree)%>
```

Comment: Please add `helper :application ` in your mailer class